# Ruby syntax error unexpected tLABEL

Tags: ruby, syntax

I have the following configuration for [using redis as a rails cache](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/31134), adapted closely from the rails doc:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  ...
  config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, url: "redis://example.com:6379/0"
  ...
end
```

Using rails 5.2.0.beta2 and ruby 2.3.1p112, my IDE is telling me the following things about the `config.cache_store =` line:

- unused literal ignored
- syntax error, unexpected tLABEL

If I enclose the hash in `{}`, the errors go away, i.e.:

```
config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: "redis://example.com:6379/0" }
```

Is the documentation in error, or is it a ruby version thing (e.g. maybe the doc is assuming ruby >= 2.4)?

In any case, I don't understand what the assignment is actually doing - how can two things be assigned to one?

Comment: I think that this case is illustrating that in multiple assignment, you cannot omit the braces around a hash.

Comment: How is it multiple assignment, though? `a, b = c, d` I understand, but this is more like `b = c, d` (braces or not).

Comment: Exactly. Ruby tries to interpret that as an array. What I am saying is that `a = b, c` (which is short for `a = [b, c]`) and `a = [b, c: d]` (short for `a = [b, {c: d}]`) are allowed, but perhaps `a = b, c: d` is not.

Comment: Right, now I get it! `a = b, c` being equivalent to `a = [b, c]` is what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

When the config block hits `cache_store` and a symbol is given, it assumes it is a cache store class and does things like:

```
:redis_cache_store.to_s.classify.constantize
# => RedisCacheStore
```

which is presumably a class. You can infer that Rails does this by looking at [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-store) and seeing that you can also pass a class.

RedisCacheStore is defined inside the `ActiveSupport::Cache` namespace, which inherits from `ActiveSupport::Cache::Store`, which is defined in `cache.rb`. This store class only initializes with a single argument of `options = nil`:

```
def initialize(options = nil)
  @options = options ? options.dup : {}
end
```

which is indicative of a requirement to pass a hash. For one reason or another, it doesn't initialize with `options = {}`, which would make your initial code correct. Hence, passing a hash like in your second example resolved the error.

Comment: Great answer. Why would a default argument of `options = {}` resolve OP's problem (which appears to be a parse error)?

Comment: Great question that I'm not fully qualified to answer because I know very little about how the Ruby interpreter works, but in my experience, it is indicative of an expression or block not ending correctly. I'm not sure where along the stack the parser hit this error so I can't answer to the specific method that was called that invoked this.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand.  Are you saying (that because of metaprogramming) that the line is roughly equivalent to: `config.cache_store = RedisCacheStore`? I don't understand how the trailing `, url: ...` fits in.

Comment: The explanation in this answer is all about what happens after parsing is done without a syntax error. The question, however, is regarding a syntax error. Hence, this answer is irrelevant to the question.